# MySQL: перенос данных из таблицы в другую

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется задача. Вынести в таблицу `OLD_ORDERS` все заказы, которые были сделаны до 1990 года.

Существуют таблицы `OLD_ORDERS` и `ORDERS` - по структуре идентичны, OLD_ORDERS пустая, данные брать из таблицы `ORDERS`.

Не пойму как реализовать данный запрос, выручайте.

Comment: так же в таблице - дата сохранена в поле ORDER_DATE

Comment: `insert into old_orders select * from orders`

Comment: экспорт -> импорт : нельзя ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы используете штатные календарные поля для хранения даты (для определенности пусть это будет поле `created_at`), тогда запрос по переносу данных может выглядеть следующим образом

```
INSERT INTO
  OLD_ORDERS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ORDERS
WHERE
  created_at < '1990-01-01'
```

После того, как данные будут перенесены, из таблицы `ORDERS` можно удалить старые записи

```
DELETE FROM
  ORDERS
WHERE
  created_at < '1990-01-01'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
insert into old_orders
select * from orders
where [Ваша дата] < '19900101'
```